# Is it possible to toggle move by display lines when wrapping is enabled with the Vintageous plug-in for Sublime Text?

Tags: vim, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I [see](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping) that in Vim, you can set up `.vimrc` to toggle movement by display lines when wrapping is on. Is this possible using the excellent Vintageous plug-in in Sublime Text 3?

For example, at the moment if I type `j` I move one physical line up or down (regardless of whether the text is soft-wrapped). To move one display line (when the the text is soft-wrapped), I need to type `gj`. I'd imagine there would be a way to automate this based on the context through the keybindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a configuration file at `packages/user/.vintageousrc`, and then add the following mappings:

```
:map j gj
:map k gk
```

Save the file, and then I had to restart sublime text.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks combination moves like dj/dk... Any ideas?